# How to use *ngIf in the component logic HTML syntax?

Tags: angular

I have the below HTML code assigned to a variable which I inject this dynamically in another template. The `*ngIf` returns false and I see in the source like `*ngIf="false"`. How can I make this condition work?

`` html: `
<img src='./assets/images/icons-pests/bug.png' class="bug-icon" 
  *ngIf="${that.getPest(field.FieldID) > 0}"/> ` ``

[image]

Note: The edit does not require for formatting the code as it will change my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sorted out:

```
html: `
      <img src='./assets/images/crops-png/${field.IconName.toLowerCase()}.png' class="crop-icon"/>
      ${that.getPest(field.FieldID) > 0 ? 
      '<img src=\'./assets/images/icons-pests/bug.png\' class="bug-icon">' : ''}
      `
```

Answer (score 1):

From your second comment it seems that you wish to show one img on said condition and the other if not met? In which case:

```
<img src="......" *ngIf="that.getPest(field.FieldID) > 0 ?; else myOtherImage" />
```

`<img #myOtherImage src="......" />`

Comment: I want to display the first one always but second with the condition. And it's not in HTML Template file.

Comment: The logic remains the same. View https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2uadg4

Comment: I voted your answer, but this does not work if you have HTML code assigned to a variable. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You mean via @Input? The view i.e. the template is loaded after the component is initialised within the cycle meaning that any variable assigned and used within template will be able to fulfill its condition. That condition could be a string, boolean [..]

So say (this.)that.getPest is given to you via @Input(), the template will be loaded once the controller is initialised therefor you will have access to its value.